# React: Expensive computation in useEffect blocking the rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When user change the select option, I need to do some time consuming work. While doing this work, I wanna show loading message, but it's not working

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    sleep(2000);
    console.log("finish");

    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [a]);
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && "loding"}
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            setA((a) => a + 1);
          }}
        >
          button
        </button>

        <select
          onChange={() => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            setA((a) => a + 1);
          }}
        >
          {[1, 2, 3].map((i) => (
            <option key={i} value={i}>
              {i}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function sleep(d) {
  let t = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - t <= d);
}
```

but it's working on button onClick event. It looks so weird!
And here is the online demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-pasteur-8vrr0?file=/src/App.js:0-908

Answer (score 4):

You need to give react time to update the screen before starting the sleep/heavy work process.

Set a after a timer:

```
 setTimeout(() => {
         setA((a) => a + 1);
      }, 50)
```

This will allow react to udapte screen with loading === true and after that, it will work on the process.

You could also try to use a webworker to offload the work form the main thread to not block the rendering. Check out [useWorker](https://github.com/alewin/useWorker).

Comment: Could this be a proof that the statement: "What does useEffect do? By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render." from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html is false?

Comment: @optimista No, actually, the problem is that you are updating both loading and A. This will cause the next render to render both. Since the above-mentioned settingA is quite expensive, so A is blocking the render, also the render of the loading. By setting a timeout we first let react render the loading and after this is rendered, A can be rendered on the next render cycle. This has nothing to do with useEffect.